# How is it possible to create a definitive edition of Finnegans Wake?

Tags: textual-history, james-joyce, finnegans-wake

In recent news, the publisher Houyhnhnm Press released a limited edition copy of *Finnegans Wake* based on 30 years of work by scholars to refine and revise the text. There are apparently some 9000 differences in all, including some in the opening paragraph:

[2010 edition](http://www.houyhnhnmpress.com/wp-content/gallery/prospectus/joyce_150110_0019.jpg):

> riverrun, past Eve and Adam’s, from swerve of shore to bend of bay,
> brings us by a commodious vicus of recirculation back to Howth Castle &
> Environs.

1939 edition:

> riverrun, past Eve and Adam’s, from swerve of shore to bend of bay,
> brings us by a commodius vicus of recirculation back to Howth Castle
> and Environs.

*Finnegans Wake* has a fairly complex publication history, with almost all of it being serialised as "*work in progress*" prior to publication of the first edition. Joyce edited it to such an extent that "*work in progress*" is considered almost a different entity to the finished work.

In addition, *Finnegans Wake* is full of purposeful mis-spellings, nonsense words and non-standard use of punctuation and text formatting for the purpose of creating puns, allusions and multiple layers of meaning for each sentence. Indeed I believe I read somewhere that Joyce himself found a multitude of "errors" in the original edition.

As such, setting a truly definitive edition of this work would seem almost impossible, especially without the direct input of Joyce himself. How, then has it been possible for modern scholars to improve on the original work with any degree of certainty that they're doing it right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether I understand what you are asking. The principles of [textual criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_criticism), which have changed throughout the centuries, are well documented in books. For this specific book, what we need is a description of the editorial methodology, which is briefly described on the [Houyhnhnm Press website](http://www.houyhnhnmpress.com/rationale).

Comment: @tsundoku aha, that second link is what I was trying to get at. I'll have a read. If you want to post a summary as an answer I will accept it otherwise perhaps I'll do it myself. Now you know the shape of the answer, how would you like the question rephrased to be clearer?

Comment: To be honest, I find that summary a bit too brief to base a good answer on. (My frame of reference is Shakespeare editions such as the Arden Shakespeare, which may devote 50 pages to the difficulties of editing the text.) With regard to your question as such, you may wish to ask something like, "What were the editorial procedures used by Danis Rose and John O'Hanlon to create the critically emended edition of *Finnegans Wake*?"